# New iTunes Connect in-app purchase doesn't appear in SKProductsResponse

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I've added a new in-app purchase item for my existing application.  This purchase will be available with the next release of the app.  The product appears to have been created correctly and the status is "Ready to submit".

Unfortunately the new product doesn't show up in the SKProductsResponse data.  I've checked "response.invalidProductIdentifiers" and it is empty.  I'm certain my app's bundle ID is correct because I'm seeing all the other in-app purchases (just not the new one).

Any ideas why this behavior would occur?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying in Production or Sandbox? In production it will not appear in the `SKProductsResponse`until fully reviewed I believe